# Is it possible to pass Java String Constants to Gradle file?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using `buildConfigField` to pass debug and release server Ip and other string literals into app.

like this:

```
 buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "url", "\"http:\\xxxxxxx.xx\""
        }

        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "url", "\"http:\\ppppppp.xx\""
        }
    }
```

But i'm having an issue that My app can communicate with multiple test servers when debug mode. Some times I point it to my local network Ip and  if i'm not in workplace, I point it to a remote test server.

The issue that i'm facing right now is that I have to Type entire IP address here whenever I wanted to change configuration :

```
 debug {
     buildConfigField "String", "url", "\"http:\\xxxxxxx.xx\""
 }
```

I have a Kotlin file with these Ip address already defined:

```
object API {
    const val URL_MAIN = "http://19.544...."
    const val URL_TEST_LOCAL = "http://192.16...."
    const val URL_TEST_REMOTE = "http://19.554...."
}
```

Is there anyway to access this variable through gradle file instead of typing it.

Edit: 
**I put these urls in Kotlin class because I need to use it's values within my project too.**

Comment: Use `BuildConfig` class, it will provide you all available variables from **buildConfigFields**.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use java strings for this, Product flavors are the perfect solution

in your android  block in Gradle file use it like this

```
productFlavors {

       main {
            dimension "app"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'url', 'http://XXXXXXX'
        }

      test_local {
            dimension "app"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'url', 'http://XXXXXXX'
        }

       test_remote {
            dimension "app"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'url', 'http://XXXXXXX'
        }


    }
```

Use Build Variant section from the bottom left corner of Android studio
and choose which build you want to make

Answer (score 1):

In the root of your project, create a file `myFile.properties` :

```
URL_MAIN = "http://19.544...."
URL_TEST_LOCAL = "http://192.16...."
URL_TEST_REMOTE = "http://19.554...."
```

Then :

```
buildTypes {
    debug  {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        properties.load(project.rootProject.file('myFile.properties').newDataInputStream())
        buildConfigField "String", "url", properties.getProperty('URL_TEST_LOCAL')
    }

    release  {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        properties.load(project.rootProject.file('myFile.properties').newDataInputStream())
        buildConfigField "String", "url", properties.getProperty('URL_MAIN')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is just to define those things in your `build.gradle`

```
def API_URL_MAIN = "http://19.544...."
def API_URL_TEST_LOCAL = "http://192.16...."
def API_URL_TEST_REMOTE = "http://19.554...."

// all your other things...

buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "url", "\"$API_URL_TEST_LOCAL\""
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "url", "\"$API_URL_MAIN\""
    }
}
```

(*you will need `"\"$<NAME_OF_YOUR_CONSTANT>\""` so that it is correctly built as `String`*)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`BuildConfig`** class which is *auto-generated class* provides you variables that are defined by **buildConfigFields** in your gradle file.

So, you'll not need to change major stuffs but some minor things in `API` object like below:

```
object API {
    const val URL_MAIN = BuildConfig.URL
}
```

Now, define this `URL` in **buildConfigField** by your build types.

```
buildConfigField "String", "URL", "\"http:\\xxxxxxx.xx\""
```

Such that for *debug* or *release* type, it can be whatever you want.

Comment: I want the `buildConfigField` to access the variable. In your example, the kotlin code is accessing the url defined in buildconfig.

Comment: So, you want `buildConfigField` to access variable other dependency. For such thing, you'll need to read it from any **property** file in gradle. Refer @Thomas's answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use   `ProductFlavours` in your Gradle File,
`ProductFlavours` are different flavours of one application. You can have multiple `buildConfigField` in your flavours which finally generate a **Build.config** file

```
productFlavors {

   name {
        minsdkversion 16
        targetsdkversion 26
        dimension "app_name"
        buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', '"http://XXXXXXX"'
    }

  name1 {
        minsdkversion 16
        targetsdkversion 26
        dimension "app_name"
        buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', '"http://XXXXXXX"'
    }

   name2 {
        minsdkversion 16
        targetsdkversion 26
        dimension "app_name"
        buildConfigField 'String', 'BASE_URL', '"http://XXXXXXX"'
    }
}
```