# Is here anyway to access gradle ext properties in java code?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

This is project level `gradle.build` file:

```
 buildscript {
    ext {
        server_test = 'http://192.618..'
        server_main = "https://68.5..."
        another_value = "test"
    }

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'

....
....
```

I'm using these values in my app level `gradle.build` file.

Is there ay way to access these variables in my Java Project files also!.

Comment: if this solves your problem please consider marking it as an answer, only if it helps :) happy coding

Comment: What are you trying to access, be specific? There are plenty of things that can be accessed in different ways

Comment: @a_local_nobody it didn't solve issue!.

Comment: what problem are you facing ? this should work

Comment: updated it now, hope it helps

Comment: It works, but not what I ask for,   I'm asking in relation with my previou question .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57004407/is-it-possible-to-pass-java-string-constants-to-gradle-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to explicitly access gradle extensions in java code, the answer is no: it's not possible, see this : [Android - Read build.gradle properties inside class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586839/android-read-build-gradle-properties-inside-class?noredirect=1&lq=1), and also see this [Is it possible to declare a variable in Gradle usable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java)

Comment: the solution to all of your problems seem to be buildConfigFields :D happy coding though

Answer (score 1):

using buildConfigFields in gradle (app level, not root level), you can :)

```
buildConfigField "String", "variable_name", "variable_value"
```

as a complete example :

```
  productFlavors {

    dev {
        dimension "your_dimension_name"

buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_TEST", "\"http://192.618..\""
buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_MAIN", "\"https://68.5...\""
buildConfigField "String", "ANOTHER_VALUE", "test"

    }
```

you can then access these variables throughout your project by using :

```
      BuildConfig.SERVER_TEST
```

Have a look at this link for a more complete answer if this didn't help :

[How to generate buildConfigField with String type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796533/how-to-generate-buildconfigfield-with-string-type)